# Orientation of Custom Tab-bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, orientation

I have added the 5 UINavigationController in my main Window. Like this

```
[self.window addSubview:navgContForBuzzyRequest.view];
[self.window addSubview:navgContForMyBuzzies.view];
[self.window addSubview:navgContForNewBuzzies.view];
[self.window addSubview:navgContForSetting.view];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

when i comment above 4 addSubView my Application perform normal Orientation but as soon as i uncomment a single UINavigationController above `[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];` my Orientation for the last addSubview is block.

As far as i have notice the View which i have addSubview first only give response to Orientation delegate

can anyone guide me what i am making wrong

Comment: it happens because orientation works with all view if one view has only UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait and other view has other orientation so that orientation not works properly

Comment: i have make Orientation delegate return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
    || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) in all my views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got you problem this happens becuase you are adding navigationController as a subView in window so that first view is set to default rootViewController so that orientation delegate methods of first is calls only.

try this

```
self.window.rootViewController=navgContForBuzzyRequest;
self.window.rootViewController=navgContForMyBuzzies;
self.window.rootViewController=navgContForNewBuzzies;
self.window.rootViewController=navgContForSetting;
self.window.rootViewController=navigationController;
```

Comment: HChouhan02 thank you for your Response but the reason for which i am addSubview them is that on button click i bring them in fornt below is my code `[self.window bringSubviewToFront:navgContForMyBuzzies.view];` can you please expain by doing `self.window.rootViewController=navgContForBuzzyRequest;`
how'll i am going to bring that view to front

Comment: oks exactly i don't what you are doing but i suggest why not you use `UITabBarController` and then put every navigationController in that.

Comment: whenever you want to the particular view to front take use this `self.window.rootViewController=navigationController;`